# How do I make mod_rewrite suppress processing more rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given my current .htaccess file, how would I modify it to check for an additional URL path like '/src/pub/*' and rewrite it to '/*' without affecting the current rewrite?

Here's the original .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and here's my recent attempt (which doesn't work):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/src/pub/(.*)$ /$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit:** Here are some examples of what I want to accomplish:

New Additional Rule:

```
From:  http://www.mysite.com/src/pub/validfile.php
To:    http://www.mysite.com/validfile.php

From:  http://www.mysite.com/src/pub/user/detail/testuser
To:    http://www.mysite.com/user/detail/testuser
```

Existing Rule (already working):

```
From:  http://www.mysite.com/user/detail/testuser
To:    http://www.mysite.com/index.php?route=user/detail/testuser
```

Comment: What does your attempt do that isn't correct?  Some examples (both correct and incorrect) would help to understand what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that the URL is being rewritten by the first rule, and then rewritten again by the second.

The solution to that is to add the "last" flag to the first rule, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/src/pub/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

within a .htaccess file, use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^src/pub/(.*)$ /$1 [R]
```

the leading "/" **will not** match within .htaccess, only within `httpd.conf` ([src](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) - bottom of page) if you wish for processing of further rules to stop, then add the `L` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^src/pub/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

rewrite log comparison (.htaccess context):

```
// using ^/src/pub/(.*)$ - leading slash will not work in .htaccess context!
(1) pass through /home/test/src

// using ^src/pub/(.*)$
(2) rewrite 'src/pub/testme' -> '/testme'
(2) explicitly forcing redirect with http://test/testme
(1) escaping http://test/testme for redirect
(1) redirect to http://test/testme [REDIRECT/302]
```