# Apache rewrite: dir/file.php?foo=bar&name=val -> file.php?newparam=dir&foo=bar&name=val

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

What is the .htaccess code for the following URL rewrite:

```
www.example.com/dir/file.php
```

into

```
www.example.com/file.php?newparam=dir
```

and

```
www.example.com/dir/file.php?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

into

```
www.example.com/file.php?newparam=dir&param=val1&param2=val2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Keng mod_rewrite URL-rewriting uses regexp to match existing URLs.

Comment: Please use descriptive titles for a question. There are [tons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941010/apache-url-rewriting) of [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285383/apache-mod-rewrite-htaccess) regarding to [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920816/apache-mod-rewrite-question) [rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430488/apache-url-rewrite-problem) in apache, most of them with non-descriptive titles.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, let me know if it works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Allow files that exist to bypass rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite remaining files
RewriteRule ^/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.php)$ /$2?newparam=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This only allows `dir` and `file.php` containing alphanumeric characters, underscore and dash.

The final rule looks for a URI matching two path components, between the forward slashes.  The first must be 1 or more characters in the given set `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+`, the second must be the same, but ending in `.php`.  The `^` and `$` characters match the front and back of the URI.  The replacement says put the second bracketed group (the `file.php` part) at the front, and put the first bracketed group (the `dir` part) as a parameter called `newparam`.  The `[L,QSA]` at the end says that this is the Last `[L]` rule if it matches, so stop matching further and perform the redirect and the `[QSA]` means "Query String Append", which adds the original query string to the end again, leaving that off would remove the original query string.

Comment: Hmm, nice. I can never figure out how QSA works but this looks promising.

Comment: QSA adds the current query string to the rewritten URL. Without QSA, the original query string would be lost.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks, should have explained really, I'll put an explanatory note.